# XSD Where value of element is name of another element

Tags: xml, xsd

I have tried many times to Google this, but it is either not possible, or the terminology I am using is incorrect. Is it possible to make an XSD for the following example:

```
<inputs>
    <input>
        <name>Test 1</name>
        <valuesTag>values_generated_15Jan2015</valuesTag>
    </input>
<inputs>
<values>
    <values_generated_15Jan2015>
        ...
    </values_generated_15Jan2015>
</values>
```

The reason for doing this is that we have only a few choices for a list of values, but a large number of inputs where each list of values is used by multiple inputs and it would be nice to not duplicate the values.

Comment: Maybe you can do it with XSD 1.1. If I understand well, for every *<valuesTag>* node, it should appear inside *<values>*,  a node with the name equal to the value of *<valuesTag>*. Which kind of content do you need inside (for example) *<values_generated_15Jan2015>*?

Comment: That is correct. The values are a list of complex numbers that can range from 50 to 1000 entries.

Comment: Is ok for you to use something like *<value id="values_generated_15Jan2015">*?

Comment: I suppose that would work. Assuming `getElementById()` works in Xerces the way I imagine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example using XSD 1.1 assertions that are explained in the comments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="inputs" type="inputsType" />
                <xs:element name="values" type="valuesType" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <!-- Ensures that there is the same number of value nodes than input nodes -->
            <xs:assert test="count(values/value) = count(inputs/input)" />
            <!-- Ensures that every value in a valueId node is unique  -->
            <xs:assert test="count(inputs/input/valueId) = count(distinct-values(inputs/input/valueId))" />
            <!-- Ensures that every value in a id attribute is unique  -->
            <xs:assert test="count(values/value) = count(distinct-values(values/value/@id))" />
            <!-- Ensures that all values in id attributes appear in valueId -->
            <xs:assert test="count(values/value[@id = ../../inputs/input/valueId]) = count(values/value)" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="inputsType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="input" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="valueId" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="valuesType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="value" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <!-- Content -->
                    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: That did work, although I had to write my own `getElementById()` Xerces was not playing nicely